# Meteor JS Iron Router Yield Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, meteor, yield, iron-router

I can't seem to render my page.  It's fairly simple but I keep getting a blank page.  When I replace {{> yield}} with {{> homePage}} in layout.html everything is peachy.  BUT, when I try to set up everything with router.js (which I at least thought I installed correctly) I get nothin'.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Here's a simple router.js inside of /lib

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('homePage', {path: '/'});
});
```

Here's a simple layout.html in /client/views/application

```
<body>
    {{> header}}

    <div id="articlesList" class="col-sm-2">
        {{> articlesList}}
    </div>

    <div id="main" class="col-sm-10">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <footer id="footer">
        {{> footer}}
    </footer>
</body>
```

Here's my template (home_Page.html) I hope to render in /client/views/home:

```
<template name="homePage">
    <section id="slider" class="col-sm-12">
        {{> slider}}
    </section>

    <div class="container">
        <article id="featuredArticle" class="col-sm-8">
            {{> featuredArticle}}
            <img src="/images/bottom-ad.png" />
        </article>

        <aside id="sidebar" class="col-sm-4">
            {{> sidebar}}
        </aside>
    </div><!--container-->
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a layoutTemplate but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Create a template named "layout" and cut/paste the content of your body : with Iron Router, you don't need to explicitly fill the body, the Router does it for you.

```
<template name="layout">
    <!-- content you put in <body> goes here ! -->
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a million.  Stupid mistake on my part.  Tired brain, tired eyes.